# How does Scala transform case classes to be accepted as functions?

Tags: scala, function, currying

I am trying to understand how a case class can be passed as an argument to a function which accepts functions as arguments. Below is an example:

Consider the below function

```
def !![B](h: Out[B] => A): In[B] = { ... }
```

If I understood correctly, this is a polymorphic method which has a type parameter `B` and accepts a function `h` as a parameter. `Out` and `In` are other two classes defined previously.

This function is then being used as shown below:

```
case class Q(p: boolean)(val cont: Out[R])
case class R(p: Int)

def g(c: Out[Q]) = {
  val rin = c !! Q(true)_
  ...
}
```

I am aware that currying is being used to avoid writing the type annotation and instead just writing `_`. However, I cannot grasp why and how the case class `Q` is transformed to a function (h) of type `Out[B] => A`.

**EDIT 1** Updated !! above and the `In` and `Out` definitions:

```
abstract class In[+A] {
  def future: Future[A]
  def receive(implicit d: Duration): A = {
    Await.result[A](future, d)
  }
  def ?[B](f: A => B)(implicit d: Duration): B = {
    f(receive)
  }
}
```

```
abstract class Out[-A]{
  def promise[B <: A]: Promise[B]
  def send(msg: A): Unit = promise.success(msg)
  def !(msg: A) = send(msg)
  def create[B](): (In[B], Out[B])
}
```

These code samples are taken from the following paper: http://drops.dagstuhl.de/opus/volltexte/2016/6115/

Comment: Maybe you should share the definition of `Out` and `In` to understand better what's going on here.

Comment: Note that case class with multiple parameter list are not really recommended.

Comment: @mfirry updated the question as requested. If you require anything else let me know. Also, please note that in order to simplify things I changed the name of the method send in the original question. It is now called `!!`, exactly as it is in the paper. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### TLDR;

Using a case class with multiple parameter lists and partially applying it will yield a partially applied `apply` call + eta expansion will transform the method into a function value:

```
val res: Out[Q] => Q = Q.apply(true) _
```

### Longer explanation

To understand the way this works in Scala, we have to understand some fundamentals behind case classes and the difference between methods and functions.

Case classes in Scala are a compact way of representing data. When you define a case class, you get a bunch of convenience methods which are created for you by the compiler, such as `hashCode` and `equals`.

In addition, the compiler also generates a method called `apply`, which allows you to create a case class instance without using the `new` keyword:

```
case class X(a: Int)

val x = X(1)
```

The compiler will expand this call to

```
val x = X.apply(1)
```

The same thing will happen with your case class, only that your case class has multiple argument lists:

```
case class Q(p: boolean)(val cont: Out[R])

val q: Q = Q(true)(new Out[Int] { })
```

Will get translated to

```
val q: Q = Q.apply(true)(new Out[Int] { })
```

On top of that, Scala has a way to transform methods, which are a [non value type](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/03-types.html#method-types), into a function type which has the type of `FunctionX`, X being the arity of the function. In order to transform a method into a function value, we use a trick called [eta expansion](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/06-expressions.html#eta-expansion-section) where we call a method with an underscore.

```
def foo(i: Int): Int = i

val f: Int => Int = foo _
```

This will transform the method `foo` into a function value of type `Function1[Int, Int]`.

Now that we posses this knowledge, let's go back to your example:

```
val rin = c !! Q(true) _
```

If we just isolate Q here, this call gets translated into:

```
val rin = Q.apply(true) _
```

Since the `apply` method is curried with multiple argument lists, we'll get back a function that given a `Out[Q]`, will create a `Q`:

```
val rin: Out[R] => Q = Q.apply(true) _
```

Answer (score 2):

> I cannot grasp why and how the case class `Q` is transformed to a function (h) of type `Out[B] => A`.

It isn't. In fact, the `case class Q` has absolutely nothing to do with this! This is all about the `object Q`, which is the *companion module* to the `case class Q`.

Every [case class](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/05-classes-and-objects.html#case-classes) has an automatically generated [*companion module*](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/05-classes-and-objects.html#object-definitions), which contains (among others) an `apply` method whose signature matches the primary constructor of the companion class, and which constructs an instance of the companion class.

I.e. when you write

```
case class Foo(bar: Baz)(quux: Corge)
```

You not only get the automatically defined case class convenience methods such as accessors for all the *elements*, `toString`, `hashCode`, `copy`, and `equals`, but you also get an automatically defined companion module that serves both as an extractor for pattern matching and as a factory for object construction:

```
object Foo {
  def apply(bar: Baz)(quux: Corge) = new Foo(bar)(quux)
  def unapply(that: Foo): Option[Baz] = ???
}
```

In Scala, `apply` is a method that allows you to create "function-like" objects: if `foo` is an object (and not a method), then [`foo(bar, baz)` is translated to `foo.apply(bar, baz)`](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/06-expressions.html#function-applications).

The last piece of the puzzle is [*η-expansion*](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/06-expressions.html#eta-expansion-section), which lifts a *method* (which is not an object) into a *function* (which *is* an object and can thus be passed as an argument, stored in a variable, etc.) There are two forms of η-expansion: *explicit* η-expansion using the `_` operator:

```
val printFunction = println _
```

And *implicit* η-expansion: in cases where Scala knows 100% that you mean a function but you give it the name of a method, Scala will perform η-expansion for you:

```
Seq(1, 2, 3) foreach println
```

And you already know about currying.

So, if we put it all together:

```
Q(true)_
```

First, we know that `Q` here *cannot possibly* be the class `Q`. How do we know that? Because `Q` here is used as a *value*, but *classes* are *types*, and like most programming languages, Scala has a strict separation between types and values. Therefore, `Q` must be a value. In particular, since we know class `Q` is a case class, object `Q` is the companion module for class `Q`.

Secondly, we know that for a value `Q`

```
Q(true)
```

is syntactic sugar for

```
Q.apply(true)
```

Thirdly, we know that for case classes, the companion module has an automatically generated `apply` method that matches the primary constructor, so we know that `Q.apply` has two parameter lists.

So, lastly, we have

```
Q.apply(true) _
```

which passes the first argument list to `Q.apply` and then lifts `Q.apply` into a function which accepts the second argument list.

Note that case classes with multiple parameter lists are unusual, since only the parameters in the first parameter list are considered *elements* of the case class, and only elements benefit from the "case class magic", i.e. only elements get accessors implemented automatically, only elements are used in the signature of the `copy` method, only elements are used in the automatically generated `equals`, `hashCode`, and `toString()` methods, and so on.